# Writing text on a curve in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I was trying to change the typeface of some text that I wrote in a tikzpicture.  I have tried a few things, but none of them seem to work.  What I current have is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\path [decorate,
       decoration={text along path, text={Sample Text}, text align={center}}]
       (-30,8) .. controls (-15,22) and (15,22) .. (30,8) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I would like to change the typeface to `qag` from the `tgadventor` font package.  Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?  I have also had difficulties changing the font colour.

Comment: If you know how to switch on the font in a normal document, you can just use the command on the text. Assume the command is `\myfont`. Then you can use `text={|\myfont|Sample Text}`, i.e. add the command between two `|`.

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger'scat.

Comment: You're welcome! Color can be added in the same way, e.g. `text={|\sffamily\color{red}|Sample Text}`. I just do not know how to use `tgadventor`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: How can one remove a question from unanswered list (questions like this that has been answered in comment)? Isn't better convert your comment to answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the font information in the text wrapped in the `text format delimiters`, the default of which is `|`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
%\usepackage[matchuppercase]{tgadventor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\path [decorate,
       decoration={text along path, text={|\itshape\color{blue}|Sample Text}, text align={center}}]
       (-30,8) .. controls (-15,22) and (15,22) .. (30,8) ;
\path [yshift=-1cm,decorate,
       decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\color{red}|Sample Text}, text align={center}}]
       (-30,8) .. controls (-15,22) and (15,22) .. (30,8) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]